# Как для alert dialog сделать свой стиль

Tags: android, view, android-dialog

Есть alert dialog, как для него сделать свой стиль, т.е. округлить края, поменять цвет фона, убрать заголовок итд

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разрабатываете нужный вам макет и добавляете его в `AlertDialog` путем вызова `setView()` в объекте `AlertDialog.Builder`. По умолчанию ваш макет заполнет окно диалога, однако при этом все равно вы все равно сможете использовать методы `AlertDialog.Builder` для добавления кнопок и настройки заголовка.